# php strpos Fatal error: Call to undefined function when using more than one if statement

Tags: php, string, strpos

To check for a products size i need to search through a simple string like: 32sdfsjkndgfjkdgndkj24**020l**dsfsfsd

To find the value inside the string i'm using strpos to look for the different sizes.

My current code is:

```
 if (strpos($size, "1875cl") || strpos($size, "01875l")) {
           $size = '18,75cl';
       } elseif (strpos($size, "20cl") || strpos($size, "020l") || strpos($size, "02l")) {
           $size = '20cl';
       }
```

The problem is when i use an if statement.

The first if is working great. Then when the elseif is checking for another value inside the string - also with strpos the scripts returns a fatal error saying that the function is undefined:

Fatal error: Call to undefined function  strpos() in .....

Comment: i believe the if statement should declares first then { for executing the accepted statement. :)

Comment: Read the docs about strpos() carefully, because the search string at the beginning of your large string won't behave as you'd expect it to do

Comment: Can you `die` the value of `$size` right before starting with the strpos?

Comment: `die` of `$size` is returning nothing at all, but when printing the value i receive the name of the product like: 32sdfsjkndgfjkdgndkj24020ldsfsfsd

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do, this code is fully functional as it stands here. when 1875cl is found the size is 18,75cl. can you try strstr instead to overcome the problem that 020l is in the first position? "Then when the elseif is checking for another value inside the string" is the same string when 1875l  already is found or another product

Comment: @Wolfeh i'm running a foreach $product and then by the name of the product i need to identify the size. First i clean the string of the name from like: cola light 0,7l --> to --> colalight07l and then to identify if the string is containing in any place (front, middle, end) the size like 07l, then it should set $size to be 0,7l

Comment: I dont need anything from the string after the size has been found. Then i just need the $size and i have another variable from earlier which then matches the size to the name.

Comment: can you do an `echo $size . '<br />';` before strpossing but in the loop and then paste here what the last value of `$size` was on screen. I guess there's something wrong with the characters of one of the $sizes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works, same as yours will work, the only possible way it would break is that the data is overwritten or there is wrong data in the `$size` variable.

You can sanitize the `$size` variable more by using `preg_replace( '/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/', '', $size );` and if you use the code below you can save the `$correctedSize` variable with the name.

```
$prodNames = array( '\x0D\x0D\x0D   \n\rkajshdfsajkdhaksjd1875cladsas', '۞ ۩ εїз Ƹ̵̡Ӝ̵̨̄kajshdfsajkdhaksjd1875cladsas', 'kajshdfsajkdhaksjd20clcladsas','02lkajshdfsajkdhaksjdadsas', 'kajshdfsajkdhaksjd1875cladsas', 'kajshdfsajkdhaksjd1875cladsas', 'kajshdfsajkdhaksjd20clcladsas','02lkajshdfsajkdhaksjdadsas' );

foreach ( $prodNames as $prodNameRaw ) {
    $correctedSize = 0; 
    $prodName = preg_replace( '/[^a-zA-Z0-9]/', '', $prodNameRaw );

    if ( strstr( $prodName, '1875cl' ) || strstr( $prodName, '01875l' ) ) {
        $correctedSize = '18,75cl';
    } elseif ( strstr( $prodName, '20cl' ) || strstr( $prodName, '020l' ) || strstr( $prodName, '02l' ) ) {
        $correctedSize = '20cl';
    }
}
```

Comment: The size variable for each of the possible outcomes is never empty and always cleaned to a perfect string with only letters and numbers.

Comment: i've gone through the string on all possible outcomes when printing the var dump. I will however try out your solution but it's running too much loops of pregreoplace i believe. I'll be back.

Comment: Perfect. With your solution i made it working. Still wondering why that error came though... hmmm. but thank you!